# How can I retrieve the favicon of a website with XSLT or JSP?

Tags: jsp, web, xslt, favicon

I want to list featured websites on my website and I thought it would be cool to honor and use their favicon.  How do I get it from the domain for an arbitrary URL in either JSP or XSLT? I can fire off PHP or javascript, but XSLT is the preferred methodology.

Comment: to get a favicon one can use this: http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=domain_name

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get the favicon of a website, you need to load the index HTML of each featured website and check for either of the following:

HTML:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/image.gif">
```

XHTML:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/somepath/image.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/somepath/image.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="/somepath/image.gif" />
```

Internet Explorer may use a slightly different format:

```html
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

Also note that since most web browsers do not require the HTML link to retrieve a favicon, you should also check for `favicon.ico` in the website's document root, if none of the above link references are found.

With PHP, it is easy to get the HTML contents of a web page by using [**`file_get_contents($url)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```php
$url = 'http://www.exmaple.com';
$output = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!  Thanks for the detail Daniel.  I will check out the PHP tutorial and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 82):

You could use Google's cache of the favicon:

`https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=https://example.com`

Comment: But in that case you are not doing the job. Google does.

Comment: 16x16px is horrible quality.

Comment: is there any way to get a 32x32?

Comment: @Meghan you can use the following similar method and specify a size parameter: `https://t0.gstatic.com/faviconV2?client=SOCIAL&type=FAVICON&fallback_opts=TYPE,SIZE,URL&url=https://aaronmeese.com&size=32`

Comment: @Meghan Add size parameter, e.g. `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=32&domain_url=yahoo.com`. It seems the latest addition to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at it. It uses various strategies to work around the many possible cases :

```
<?
/*
  nws-favicon : Get site's favicon using various strategies

  This script is part of NWS
  https://github.com/xaccrocheur/nws/

*/


function CheckImageExists($imgUrl) {
    if (@GetImageSize($imgUrl)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};

function getFavicon ($url) {

$fallback_favicon = "/var/www/favicon.ico";    
// $fallback_favicon = "http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico";


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($url);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
    $l = $links->length;
    $favicon = "/favicon.ico";
    for( $i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
        $item = $links->item($i);
        if( strcasecmp($item->getAttribute("rel"),"shortcut icon") === 0) {
            $favicon = $item->getAttribute("href");
            break;
        }
    }

    $u = parse_url($url);

    $subs = explode( '.', $u['host']);
    $domain = $subs[count($subs) -2].'.'.$subs[count($subs) -1];

    $file = "http://".$domain."/favicon.ico";
    $file_headers = @get_headers($file);

    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND' || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently') {

        $fileContent = @file_get_contents("http://".$domain);

        $dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($fileContent);
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

        $elements = $xpath->query("head/link//@href");

        $hrefs = array();

        foreach ($elements as $link) {
            $hrefs[] = $link->value;
        }

        $found_favicon = array();
        foreach ( $hrefs as $key => $value ) {
            if( substr_count($value, 'favicon.ico') > 0 ) {
                $found_favicon[] = $value;
                $icon_key = $key;
            }
        }

        $found_http = array();
        foreach ( $found_favicon as $key => $value ) {
            if( substr_count($value, 'http') > 0 ) {
                $found_http[] = $value;
                $favicon = $hrefs[$icon_key];
                $method = "xpath";
            } else {
                $favicon = $domain.$hrefs[$icon_key];
                if (substr($favicon, 0, 4) != 'http') {
                    $favicon = 'http://' . $favicon;
                    $method = "xpath+http";
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($favicon)) {
            if (!CheckImageExists($favicon)) {
                $favicon = $fallback_favicon;
                $method = "fallback";
            }
        } else {
            $favicon = $fallback_favicon;
            $method = "fallback";
        }

    } else {
        $favicon = $file;
        $method = "classic";

        if (!CheckImageExists($file)) {
            $favicon = $fallback_favicon;
            $method = "fallback";
        }

    }
    return $favicon;
}

?>
```

Comment: Nice. But, doesn't seem to pick up the favicon for plenty of urls I tried throwing at it.

Comment: Wow, this is old code ; My latest version is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/favrat

Comment: Nice and interesting that you went for a js approach. I threw together a quick and dirty solution in PHP. I prefer the PHP, as it allows me also easily cache the results.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox you could use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/. Load a website then press F10 > ... > "open HttpFox in own Window" then look for "image/x-icon"; in the column to the right is the URL.

Answer (score 0):

- Using IE, bookmark the site
- Drag the shortcut from your bookmarks menu onto your desktop
- Open the resulting .URL using a (real) text editor
- There will be a line in the file for **IconFile**, which will point
  to the favicon file on the web server
- Browse to the file... viola!

Answer (score -1):

Open the page source code (right click View page source) find the below mentioned line, click the images/favicon.png link.

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
```

Comment: The question specifically says "in either JSP or XSLT", indicating that the user wanted to dynamically retrieve the favicon without manually navigating through their DOM