# How to get larger favicon from Google's api?

Tags: favicon

Is it possible to get a larger version of the favicon from the Google's api or from somewhere else?

This is the url.
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com

I searched for an alternative api on ProgrammableWeb and Google but many of them don't exist anymore and the one I found that actually seems to work isn't free. (http://grabicon.com/)

I need the icon for a VB.NET project that has a list of websites with icons. But 16x16 icons are too small for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favicons are specified either as part of the HTML page, the HTTP response to a request for a page, or simply by being hosted at a default location.

That's true for all sites. There's plenty of browser extensions that can help you figure out the favicons a page send, if you don't manage by hand. For example, right clicking in firefox, "Page Info", "Media", "sort by type"->"Icon" should show all icons that a browser can find. It's not usual to have Icons larger than 32x32, and google might not be an exception.

Also be aware that the .ico format can contain multiple Icon sizes that not all tools show. So saving that .ico on your computer and inspecting it with a tool known to deal with all sizes contained in a single file might help.

Last word of advice: You're dealing with the logo, the *very core of their brand*, of a multi-billion dollar company. You might want to check with their policy of using that logo in your project. Probably it's OK (for example, browser don't seem to get in trouble for having a google logo for their google search box), but I'd still take care not to raise the impression that you're association a product of your own making with their logo.

Answer (score 55):

looks like there is size parameter in google now.

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain_url=yahoo.com

Comment: Great, it works. But can someone find information about the usage of this url and why or on which terms it's offered?

Comment: Where is the documentation about this size parameter? Because following the provided link gives a poor quality yahoo logo/icon 

Comment: @BernoulliIT When I change the parameter to `256`, i.e. `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=256&domain_url=yahoo.com`, it give me some what better quality. `512` just give me `16px`.

Comment: Nice one @bayuah 

Answer (score 11):

**Editted:**
The below answer is no longer valid, but the code is freely available on github:

Github -> [Favicons for all!](https://github.com/ao/favicons)

**Original answer**

You can also try [Statvoo's Favicon API](https://statvoo.com), e.g.

https://api.statvoo.com/favicon/?url=google.com

https://api.statvoo.com/favicon/?url=stackoverflow.com

etc..

They also have quite a few other API's you can use if you look around. Most of which are free and have been around for years.

Comment: compared to the answer(added below) I found from other sources: https://api.faviconkit.com/dogster.com/100

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Google has an size attribute too.

https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain_url=https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 5):

According to https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17190599:

> Unless that endpoint can also return other resolutions, Favicon Kit
>   offers more: https://api.faviconkit.com/twitter.com/144
>   https://api.faviconkit.com/twitter.com/16
>
> (Though, I will say, the URIs returned for Twitter and the image sizes
>   don't actually align in those cases. The first is actually 192ˣ192
>   pixels, and the second is 32ˣ32 pixels. That seems odd. Maybe they
>   should have endpoints like domain/large, domain/medium, domain/small?)

Comment: However it does have a rate limit

Comment: Finally an answer that **really** results in good quality large(r) favicons 

Comment: Loads slower. At least its fallback icon is better than Google's.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some Favicon Fetchers I have found

- [Free Favicon-Service by AllesEDV.at](https://favicon.allesedv.com/) - https://f1.allesedv.com/stackoverflow.com
- Google Favicon Snatcher - https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com
- [Favicon Grabber](https://favicongrabber.com/) - http://favicongrabber.com/api/grab/stackoverflow.com

For [Favicon Grabber](https://favicongrabber.com/) it will return as JSON list of icon URLs.

Alternatively you can load the main page of the site and figure it out from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1990487/