# How to pick the page icon tab and put as icon link in my body page Html, Css

Tags: html, css

I was doing a page with a list of sites I need to visit daily, such as exercise to learn Html, CSS. I would like to know if it is possible to create a link with a page icon that is in the upper tab of the browser (chrome).

Ex: I want to list StackOverflow on my site. So I create a link and for the icon, I want to use the image that is on the tab of the page itself, as in this:

[image]

Comment: include details (code etc)  on what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=www.yourlink.com
```

**example**

```html
<a href="">
  <img src="https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=www.stackoverflow.com"> Stackoverflow
</a>
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! After searching about it, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599939/how-to-get-larger-favicon-from-googles-api) with some other APIs that do something similar (some return larger images).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly getting what you want, you'd need to either have a local copy or link to the sites' favicon, like so:

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" /></a>
```